# How to traverse this object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-1.1

I am getting an object from a web service call and I am storing that in a hidden field by serializing the object.
Then I am deserilizing the object and it is coming like the below screenshot :

[image]

My problem is when I am trying to access the below information by many ways, I an getting
***Invalid cast error*** OR ***System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid***

```
decodedValues[0][2].Value
decodedValues[1][2].Value
decodedValues[2][2].Value
```

--etc

Any idea how can I get it in **ASP.NET 1.1**?

Comment: How about instead of giving us a screenshot, you give us some code indicating where your data has come from and what form it takes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought giving scrrenshot would give more information than what I will write..My only need is to fetch those values..and whatever I tried gave me Invalid cast error..

Comment: Well the invalid cast error itself is something you should have told us about. Code is almost *always* better than a screenshot. (And wow, ASP.NET 1.1? Crikey.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method would do the trick:

```
public string[] GetValues(object[] decodedValues)
{
    string[] returnValues = new string[decodedValues.Length];

    for(int i=0; i<decodedValues.Length; i++)
    {
        returnValues[i] = ((XmlAttribute[])decodedValues[i])[2].Value;
    }

    return returnValues;
}
```

But remember: If the types from your screenshot don't match, you'll get your `InvalidCastException`.. So there is room for some improvement to check if the types match.

Comment: Got it..System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid... Is there something wrong in my object?

Comment: When the exception arrises, you should check if the specified member of the decodedValues array is a XmlAttribute[]

Comment: I have checked..this what it is at runtime.. `decodedValues = System.Object[]` , 

`decodedValues[0] = System.Xml.XmlAttribute[]` ,

`decodedValues[0][2] = System.Xml.XmlText` ,

`decodedValues[0][2].Value = string`